# How to save a Video file on android using capacitor and angular

Tags: android, angular, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

my code in angular is:

```
async downloadFilm() {
  if (confirm(this.filmData.filmTitel + ' herunterladen?')) {
    if(this.api.getIsWeb()){
      this.api.downloadFilm(parseInt(this.filmData.id)).subscribe(async data => {
        console.log(data)
        let fileName = this.filmData.filmTitel + '.mp4';
        saveAs(data, fileName);
      })
    } else {
      this.api.downloadFilm(parseInt(this.filmData.id)).subscribe(async data => {
        //TODO Android Download
      });
    }
  } else {
    alert('Download abgebrochen');
  }
}
```

i tryed using this in the place of //TODO Android Download

```
const fileName = this.filmData.filmTitel + '.mp4';
const fileContent = data;
await Filesystem.writeFile({
  path: fileName,
  data: fileContent,
  directory: Directory.Documents,
  encoding: Encoding.UTF8
}).then(() => {
  alert('File saved');
}).catch(err => {
  alert(err);
});
```

but when i use alert to show the error on the phone, it said "Error: "Filesystem" plugin is not implemented on android".

is there any way i can download a mp4 file to an android 12 phone using both angular and capacitor?